# How can I create a "start" "end" time table from a timestamp list

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to create a view that displays the time of employee stamps.

This is what the table looks like now:

| Person | Person_Number | Date | Stamp_number | Time_Stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 1 | 8:00 |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 2 | 10:00 |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 3 | 10:30 |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 4 | 12:00 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 22-10-23 | 1 | 9:00 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 22-10-23 | 2 | 11:00 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 22-10-23 | 3 | 12:00 |

And I would like it to look like this using only a `select` query

| Person | Person_Number | Date | Start | End | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 8:00 | 10:00 | 2:00 |
| Paul | 1 | 22-10-24 | 10:30 | 12:00 | 1:30 |
| Jimmy | 2 | 22-10-23 | 9:00 | 11:00 | 2:00 |
| Jimmy | 1 | 22-10-23 | 12:00 | null | null |

Is it possible ?

Comment: How do you know what is a "start" time and what is an "end"?

Comment: @Larnu with the `stamp_number`... it reset each day.  it's incremental. +1 each time you add a time

Comment: But nothing against the 2nd row, for example, denotes it's an *end* value. How do you know it isn't a second start time?

Comment: @Larnu because it's always start/end/start/end/start, etc... there's no "second start time". 1 is always a start, 2 is always an end, 3 always a start, etc.

Comment: @Larnu The requirement is to form start-end pairs for each pair of records within a given person/date group.  Should a given start _not_ have any matching end (indicating that this record is last in the group, and it's odd man out), then `NULL` should be reported for the end date.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I could have guessed this, but I didn't want to. Far too often, it the real world, a second row doesn't always mean it's a "end" time, and hence why I wanted to OP to confirm that they "trusted" their data, as I didn't without explicit information that they did. Far too often do we see qusetions like this only to find out that the data *isn't* always start end start end start end...

Comment: @LouisChopard - Since the Stamp Number counter is restarted at the beginning of the day, this whole thing goes to hell in a handbasket if a person punched in late one night and punched out early the next day.  The ROW_NUMBER() trick won't save us unless there's some way to guarantee that the first punch for each person is a Start punch.

Comment: @JeffModen You are right thank you. But this case never happen in my company.

Comment: @LouisChopard - I sure hope you're right.  While there are some exceptions, I've found that the word "NEVER" is almost never true. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use conditional aggregation along with a `ROW_NUMBER` trick:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person_Number, Date
                                 ORDER BY Stamp_number) - 1 rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT Person, Person_Number, Date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN Time_Stamp END) AS [Start],
       MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN Time_Stamp END) AS [End],
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 0 THEN Time_Stamp END),
                MAX(CASE WHEN rn % 2 = 1 THEN Time_Stamp END)) AS Duration
FROM cte
GROUP BY Person, Person_Number, Date, rn / 2
ORDER BY 2, 4;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xkW_7d4H).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT Person, Person_Number, Date, [Start], [End],
  CONVERT(TIME(0), CONVERT(DATETIME, [End]) - CONVERT(DATETIME, [Start])) AS Duration
FROM
  (
    SELECT Person, Person_Number, Date, MIN(Time_Stamp) AS [Start], 
     CASE 
       WHEN MAX(Time_Stamp) <> MIN(Time_Stamp) 
       THEN MAX(Time_Stamp) 
     END AS [End] /* To select End as null when there is no End for a Start */
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY Person, Person_Number, Date, (Stamp_number+1)/2
  ) T
ORDER BY Person_Number, Date, [Start]
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z6FkYokJ).